# Jquery get value from object by form field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want some help to my problem, i try to get values from a data object from a form field name.

**Example**
i want from fields names to retrieve the value from Data object from current path

1st field is "**post**" => i want from Data the "post" field

2st field is "**recipes[0][recipe_desc_en]**" => i want from Data the "recipes->0->recipe_desc_en" field

3st field is "**recipes[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve67Z.png)[recipe_desc_en]**" => this is not exist from Data object

Here the object data

```
  data: Object
    post: "hello world"
    recipes: Array[1]
      0: Object
        recipe_desc_en: "t1"
      1: Object
        recipe_desc_en: "t2"
```

here the form

```
<form>
<input name='post'/>
<input name='recipes[0][recipe_desc_en]'/>
<input name='recipes[1][recipe_desc_en]'/>
</form>
```

here my starting code

```
  $('input', form).each(function () {
    var val = data.data[$(this).data("name")];
    console.log(val);
    //field post working
    //field recipes[0][recipe_desc_en] not working
  });
```

Here the object data

[image]

Comment: [img](http://cdn.cdl.gr/upload/uploads/08-2015/1439358692_1ca3c9585553dae1bfcaf4929c3a3171.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of recipes[0][recipe_desc_en]  ,  try recipes[0].recipe_desc_en

The data recipes looks like an array of objects, so using "." is how you would access that attribute.

Let me know!

Comment: i want from fields names to retrieve the value from Data object from current path example 
1st field is "post" => i want from Data the "post" field
2st field is "recipes[0][recipe_desc_en]" => i want from Data the "recipes->0->recipe_desc_en" field
3st field is "recipes[1][recipe_desc_en]" => this is not exist from Data object